# My webpack.config.js cant read any image file - Angular 8

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am building a Angular 8 application, but I am getting an error when I build it. I don't know how to load images in the webpack. I've treied a few aproaches, but nothing worked. I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/images/icon_transparent.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./src/app/shared/navigation/navigation.component.html 1:265-326
 @ ./src/app/shared/navigation/navigation.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
```

Does the version of the webpack I am using affect this?

My webpack.config.js is this one:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/'),
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            },

            // workaround for warning: System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead.
            {
                test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                parser: { system: true }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // global app config object
            config: JSON.stringify({
                apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
            })
        }),

        // workaround for warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        )
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
        },
        runtimeChunk: true
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the page the error message suggests? You indeed do not have any loader for .png files in the rules list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that should be used as external resources (like images, fonts etc.) rather than being bundled into javascript code, must be loaded with an appropriate [webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/). Usually it is the webpack's native [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/).

```
// add this to your rules array
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
  use: 'file-loader'
}
```

[More about loading images with webpack](https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/images/).

Also consider using [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) instead of webpack. It's generally  works faster and you don't waste time writing webpack config.

Comment: I don't agree. using custom webpack we can get a lot of customization than angular cli provides. we can go beyond with webpack.